# Barra de rolagem personalizada

Tags: css, css3

preciso de ajuda para ajustar uma barra de rolagem que personalizei, ela funciona perfeitamente no chrome, opera e mozilla, mas no ie e no safari não funciona, segue prints e códigos.

[image: Print no Chrome]

[image: Print ios(safari)]

```
#aulas-do-curso::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #e3e0d6;
}

#aulas-do-curso::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #282828;
}

#aulas-do-curso::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #57AF33;
}
```

Comment: Esquece o IE, nem a Microsoft está mais dando suporte para ele, e deve ser totalmente abandonado nos próximos meses. Sobre o Safari, verifique se seu público realmente usa esse browser, a chance é que menos de 5% use... E caso queira algo realmente cross-browse vc pode usar o Nice Scroll que é uma barra de rolagem feita em JS

Comment: No ie eu ate não importo, mas eu precisava que funcionasse no safari, por css não tem como ajeitar? com esse nice scroll eu consigo personalizar do jeito que postei a print?

Answer (score 0):

Eu verifico sempre a compatibilidade desses pseudo-elementos de CSS pela documentação da **Mozilla**, lá está falando que há suporte no `Safari` na versão `4` e no `Safari IOS` na versão `3`.

O `Internet Explorer` **não oferece suporte** para estilização da scrollbar.

Com relação ao seu código me parece estar correto, apenas utilizaria `background` no lugar de `background-color`, segundo testes da comunidade chega a ser até 2x mais rápido na maioria dos casos para renderizar.

- Link da Documentação para mais informações: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

[image: Browser Compatibility Scrollbar]